# Recover WhatsApp messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I factory reset my phone and then installed WhatsApp. Before that, I had created a backup of my conversations on my SD card, the name of the backup was 'msgstore.db.crypt'.

After I installed WhatsApp and after entering my number, I got an option to restore my conversations. I clicked restore. It loaded for a minute then I had to enter my name and other things. After I finished everything, no conversations were retrieved. I have the backup in `databases` folder, but it's not working.

What should I do?